# During the Exodus, why didn't God house the Israelites in real Succot?

Tags: parshanut-torah-comment, sukkah

> "לְמַעַן יֵדְעוּ דֹרֹתֵיכֶם כִּי בַסֻּכּוֹת הוֹשַׁבְתִּי אֶת־בְּנֵי יִשְׂרָאֵל בְּהוֹצִיאִי אוֹתָם מֵאֶרֶץ מִצְרָיִם...׃
> in order that future generations may know that I made the Israelite people live in booths when I brought them out of the land of Egypt, ...

First, dwelling in Succot is mentioned nowhere in the Torah, the Israelites lived in tents in the wilderness (e.g. "מה טבו אהליך יעקב"ׁ.

In rabbinic interpretation (Tanhuma, Beshalach) Succot were interpreted as the Clouds of Honor, that turned into a six-fold structure: "שבעה ענני כבוד היו: ארבע מארבע רוחות, ואחד מלמטה, ואחד מלמעלה, ואחד מהלך לפניהם." and then allowed for this metaphorical interpretation of Succah. However, only one cloud is only mentioned as moving in front and behind the camp, and occasionally covering the Tabernacle. So it doesn't fit the text either.

So, why didn't God actually house the Israelites in Succot but did write about it in the Torah and command them to remember it?

Comment: "_Again, I ask about the explicit text, not about the interpreters who speculated that the Israelites did dwell in Succos, despite the clear contradiction to the text_". The explicit text doesn't say they were surrounded by clouds, in formations like succos, either. So, you're really just asking based on one interpreter's speculation (the one you prefer?), to the exclusion of the other. Both interpretations are brought in the [Sifra on Vayikra 23:43](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Sifra%2C_Emor%2C_Chapter_17.11?lang=bi&lang2=en).

Comment: "_According to the Biblical narrative, the Israelites dwelled in tents in the wilderness_". How do you know 'tents' mean a specific form of [temporary] dwelling, to the exclusion of succos?

Comment: "_Given the metaphorical importance of sitting in real Succah_ ..." What metaphorical importance was there to necessitate them dwelling in real succos for the duration of their travel through the wilderness, that we get away with doing it for only seven-eight days in a year?

Comment: @TamirEvan Thank you, I edited the question, see if it sounds clearer.

Comment: @TamirEvan I did not refer to the tradition, I only refer to God's reason "כי בסכות הושבתי".

Comment: You have no basis to say that the Jews didn't dwell in sukkos. What do you mean it doesn't say? You quote the very verse which says they were in sukkos! What more do you want. It doesn't say they dwelled in tents. You're reading into the verse ma tovu the rabbinic interpretation. You can't do that there and then ignore it here...

Comment: @AlBerko "_I did not refer to the tradition_..." What (that I said) are you responding to?

Comment: "_In rabbinic interpretation (Tanhuma, Beshalach) Succot were interpreted as the Clouds of Honor_ ..." I don't see Succot mentioned in [Tanhuma Beshalach 3](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Midrash_Tanchuma%2C_Beshalach.3.1?lang=bi) (nor in [Tanchuma Buber Bamidbar](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Midrash_Tanchuma_Buber%2C_Bamidbar.2.1?lang=bi), nor [Mekhilta DeRabbi Shimon Bar Yochai 13](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Mekhilta_DeRabbi_Shimon_Bar_Yochai.13.20?lang=bi&lang2=en), that mention there being _seven_ Clouds of Honor).

Comment: Also, according to [Sifrei Bamidbar 83](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Sifrei_Bamidbar.83.1?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en), not all agreed that there were seven Clouds of Honor (in translation): "_R. Yehudah says: There were **thirteen** (clouds) — two on each side, two above and two below, and one before them. R. Yoshiyah says: **Four**. Rebbi says: **Two**_"

Comment: There’s even one opinion that says that ה׳made it rain wood, in which the yidden built succos out of!

Answer (score -2):

Were Israelite Sukkot סֻּכּ֗וֹת “Booths” simply Ohalim אֹהָלִים “Tents”? - No.

**The Sukkot were temporary Clouds over the Ohel Moed & Ohalim of Yisrael, if we consider Shemot 40:35-40 & Bamidbar 24:5 in context to Vayiqra 23:42-43.**

When Balaam raised his eyes and saw Israel dwelling according to its tribes, and the spirit of God rested upon him - Did God confirm through Balaam that Sukkot were good “Tents”?

[Bamidbar | Numbers 24:5] “How goodly are your tents, O Jacob, your dwelling places, O Israel!” ( מַה־טֹּ֥בוּ אֹֽהָלֶ֖יךָ יַֽעֲקֹ֑ב מִשְׁכְּנֹתֶ֖יךָ יִשְׂרָאֵֽל )

Ohaley-kha אֹֽהָלֶ֖יךָ “your-Tents”? Shouldn’t Israelites be in Sukkot “Booths” based on Leviticus 23:42-43?

**When God speaks through Moshe instead of Balaam, we learn Israelites lived in סֻּכּ֗וֹת Booths instead of Tents?**

[Vayiqra | Leviticus 23:42-43] “For a seven day period you shall live in booths. Every resident among the Israelites shall live in booths” (בַּסֻּכֹּ֥ת תֵּֽשְׁב֖וּ שִׁבְעַ֣ת יָמִ֑ים כָּל־הָֽאֶזְרָח֙ בְּיִשְׂרָאֵ֔ל יֵֽשְׁב֖וּ בַּסֻּכֹּֽת) “in order that future generations may know that I made the Israelite people live in booths when I brought them out of the land of Egypt, I YHVH your God.” (לְמַ֘עַן֘ יֵֽדְע֣וּ דֹרֹֽתֵיכֶם֒ כִּ֣י בַסֻּכּ֗וֹת הוֹשַׁ֨בְתִּי֙ אֶת־בְּנֵ֣י יִשְׂרָאֵ֔ל בְּהֽוֹצִיאִ֥י אוֹתָ֖ם מֵאֶ֣רֶץ מִצְרָ֑יִם אֲנִ֖י יְהֹוָ֥ה אֱלֹֽהֵיכֶֽם)

**Were there any Sukkot (Coverings) over their Ohel?**

[Shemot | Exodus 40:34]
And the cloud covered the Tent of Meeting, and the glory of the Lord filled the Mishkan. (וַיְכַ֥ס הֶֽעָנָ֖ן אֶת־אֹ֣הֶל מוֹעֵ֑ד וּכְב֣וֹד יְהֹוָ֔ה מָלֵ֖א אֶת־הַמִּשְׁכָּֽן)

[Shemot | Exodus 40:35]
Moshe could not enter the Tent of Meeting because the cloud rested upon it and the glory of the Lord filled the Mishkan. (וְלֹֽא־יָכֹ֣ל משֶׁ֗ה לָבוֹא֙ אֶל־אֹ֣הֶל מוֹעֵ֔ד כִּֽי־שָׁכַ֥ן עָלָ֖יו הֶֽעָנָ֑ן וּכְב֣וֹד יְהֹוָ֔ה מָלֵ֖א אֶת־הַמִּשְׁכָּֽן)

[Shemot | Exodus 40:38]
For the cloud of the Lord was upon the Mishkan by day, and there was fire within it at night, before the eyes of the entire house of Israel in all their journeys. (כִּי֩ עֲנַ֨ן יְהֹוָ֤ה עַל־הַמִּשְׁכָּן֙ יוֹמָ֔ם וְאֵ֕שׁ תִּֽהְיֶ֥ה לַ֖יְלָה בּ֑וֹ לְעֵינֵ֥י כָל־בֵּֽית־יִשְׂרָאֵ֖ל בְּכָל־מַסְעֵיהֶֽם)

**The Sukkot were temporary Clouds over the Ohel Moed & Ohalim of Yisrael.**

Comment: Are you suggesting Rabbi Eliezer in the [Sifra](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Sifra%2C_Emor%2C_Chapter_17.11?lang=bi&lang2=en) (or Rabbi Akiva in [Sukka 11b](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Sukkah.11b.15?lang=bi&lang2=en), where they seem to flip who said what), who said "סוכות ממש היו" (as opposed to "ענני כבוד היו"), is plain wrong??

Comment: First, you don't need to shout in bold to prove your points. Second, you rely on the same verse to prove its truthfulness, when the question was why didn't the Torah mention Israel dwelling in Succos.